# Mean.js server side redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, meanjs

I have an external software that sends users to my website, and based off the parameters in the URL i want to redirect the users to the correct page, however I cannot get the redirect to work correctly.

The urls used by the external software are

```
www.mysite/#/ref?param1=value&param2=value
```

In my routes/requests.server.routes.js file I handle the requests:

**in /app/routes/requests.server.routes.js:**

```
app.route('/ref*')
    .get(requests.create);
```

So all requests to /ref are handled by the requests.create function which creates a record of the reqeust and is meant to redirect the user:

**in /app/controllers/requests.server.controller.js:**

```
 exports.create = function(req, res) {
var request = new Request(req.query);
    request.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            console.log(req.query.param1 + ' This prints the correct value');
            return res.redirect('/something/'+req.query.param1);

        }
    });

};
```

The request gets saved, but the redirect doesn't work.
The url becomes www.mysite.com/#%2Fref%param1=value&param2=value
I would really appreciate any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong, TIA!

Comment: does it reach this part: 
 `else { return res.redirect('/something/'+req.query.param1); }` ?

Comment: yes it does @user1695032

Comment: Does the redirect do nothing at all or redirect you to a wrong place? Because i tried your setup and it works for me.

Comment: Nothing after the hash gets sent to server. Your query params are only part of the hash

Comment: it redirects to the wrong place, the url looks like this: www.mysite.com/#%2Fref%3Fparam1=value&param2=value, instead of www.mysite.com/something/value